# if statement is not working, it is automatically using else statement

Tags: python, django

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

def register(request):

     if request.method == 'POST':

         first_name = request.POST['first_name']
         last_name = request.POST['last_name']
         username = request.POST['username']
         email = request.POST['email']
         password1 = request.POST['password1']
         password2 = request.POST['password2']
         user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password1,email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
         user.save()
         return render(request, 'register.html')

     else:
        return HttpResponse('run')
```

Comment: If the `else` is being entered, `request.method == 'POST'` must be false.

Comment: I don't even understand the question -- it's obvious that `request.method` does not equal "POST".

Comment: In your own words, why do you think it should not do what it is doing?

Comment: The error lies with `request.method` not being equal to `"POST"` when you want it to. Maybe provide some information on your forms?

Comment: See I am making an registration page .. in which the user will fill there details and then click on the submit button and after that it will redirect to the home page,. That is why I have put an if else statement . But the problem is that it is ignoring the if statement and just stick to the else one don't know I am able to understand you or not I am just a biggne but the problem is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to initialize your form object, which would have been defined in *forms.py* by convention.

For example:

```py
from .forms import ContactDetailsForm

def home_view(request):
    """The Home Page"""

    # Initiate forms
    form = ContactDetailsForm(request.POST or None)

    # check request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            redirect('register')
    else:
        redirect('home')
```

In this example, `ContactForm` would be defined in *forms.py*, by convention

```py
# in forms.py
from .models import ContactDetail

class ContactDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='')

    class Meta:
        model = ContactDetail # model used from models.py
```

And, by convention, `ContactDetail` would be imported from *models.py*, where it was defined as:

```py
# in models.py

class ContactDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(default='', verbose_name='Preferred Email')
```

Of course your forms and models and views will likely be more complicated than that. This is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Python isn't broken in if statements, in that I can assure you with all confidence I have.
Try using an IDE with debugger if you are having any doubt's how code is executed

Comment: See I am making an registration page .. in which the user will fill there details and then click on the submit button and after that it will redirect to the home page,. That is why I have put an if else statement . But the problem is that it is ignoring the if statement and just stick to the else one .

Comment: I don't know I am able to understand you or not I  am just a biggne but  the problem is happening...

Comment: so, run your app with debug, there is a setting in VS Code to debug Django application, put a breakpoint at the beggining. study what methods and field a request has. also make sure that you understand the flow.
first user will have GET method and the function should return an html page, after he will submit form launching POST request, you should process data, create user and redirect if success. you have this 2 kinda mixed